# django admin page and JWT

Tags: django, jwt

We are using django-rest-framework with django-rest-framework-jwt for authentication and it works everywhere except the django admin page at `ip:port/admin/`. That still wants username and password.

Is there a setting or way to bypass that so it recognizes the JWT?

Is the `/admin/` page always required to use name/password?  I think the built in token auth works with it.

jwt is the only auth set in the settings.py file.  Session authentication is not in there anymore.

Comment: I apologize if there is something simple that I may have just overlooked. I have used extensions to insert the JWT directly into the request header and that works for all urls except `/admin/`  it works for `/schemaview/` and even the rest-framework api view.

Comment: Hi, having the same issue and looking for the same solution here. Could you figure out something in the meantime ?

Comment: I have not yet figured it out. It is not a high priority task for me at the moment but something nice I may need in the near future.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that Django isn't aware of djangorestframework-jwt, but only djangorestframework, itself. The solution that worked for me was to create a simple middleware that leveraged the auth of djangorestframework-jwt

In settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # others
    'myapp.middleware.jwt_auth_middleware',
]
```

Then in my myapp/middleware.py

```
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from rest_framework import exceptions

def jwt_auth_middleware(get_response):
    """Sets the user object from a JWT header"""
    def middleware(request):
        try:
            authenticated = JSONWebTokenAuthentication().authenticate(request)
            if authenticated:
                request.user = authenticated[0]
            else:
                request.user = AnonymousUser
        except exceptions.AuthenticationFailed as err:
            print(err)
            request.user = AnonymousUser

        response = get_response(request)

        return response

    return middleware
```

**Important Note:**
This is a naive approach that you shouldn't run in production so I only enable this middleware `if DEBUG`. If running in production, you should probably cache and lazily evaluate the user as done by the builtin `django.contrib.auth` module.

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be not in the authentication method you use. If you customize `User` model, it can happen that `create_superuser` method doesn't update `is_active` flag in user instance details to `True`. This case django authentication backend (if you use `ModelBackend`) can recognize that user is not active and do not allow to authenticate. Simple check - just see what value has `is_active` field of the superuser you create. If it `False`, update it manually to `True`, and try to login. If it is the reason of your problem you need to override `create_superuser` and `create_user` method of UserManager class.

Comment: I have been using an active user.  Using the chrome modify request I add the token to the header.  I can access everything except the /admin/ page.  It has been a while now nice working with this. I will double check and verify