# Django Admin use JWT

Tags: django, django-admin, jwt

## Using:

- Django 1.11
- Python 3.6
- DRF with JWT in FE

I understand that the Django admin uses a session, and basic authentication.

## What I did so far: Replaced the Django Admin authentication signin page with AWS-Cognito:

- The user goes to `domain/admin/*`, redirected to signin in AWS
- On successful signin the user is redirected to the `redirect_uri`, leads to a Django View
- In the view I replace the `code` with tokens
- I can't navigate to any Admin page - I am trying to redirect, but that doesn't work since I didn't `login()` the User
- Stuck - I would like to associate the User with the fetched tokens and authenticate with every Admin page request, and when the user logs out delete the tokens

## What to do next?

- When I use JWT with the Front End application, every `request.META` has `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`, and uses a suitable backend.
- I know how to add backends, and potentially leverage the user.backend (I also use Cognito-JWT for other FE portions, so already wrote BE for that)
- I need to find a way to replace the Django Admin sessions authentication with the fetched token

Thank you!

## EDIT:

If I `login()` the user, and set it to a model backend that I have already I can navigate to any admin page - but using the session that I created when I logged the user in.

I would like to have the user be set to a new model backend, with authentication that uses a token (from [Django backend docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)):

```
class MyBackend:
    def authenticate(self, request, token=None):
        # Check the token and return a user.
        ...
```

1. How do I make the different Admin pages requests pass the token to the authentication?
2. Where do I store the token? (I could make a `NewUserModel` that is 1-1 with the Django User model, and place a token field there)
3. I am thinking of writing a middleware to capture all requests, and looking into the target URL - if Admin url, add the token to the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` once I fetch the user mentioned in #2 (the user is in every request due to DRF)

## EDIT 2

My solution is getting more and more like [this stack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49679059/django-admin-page-and-jwt), I would have liked to know if there are any other options, but here is what I did so far:

1. I made a model that has a 1-1 user field, and a tokens field
2. As I am fetching/creating the user, I am also saving the tokens on the user's related model from #1 above
3. I created a middleware that is capturing any request in `process_request`, and has access to the user. I can see the tokens there as I access the user's related model from #1 above.
4. I am trying to set the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header on the request, but cannot do that yet (currently stuck here)
5. In my backend, I am looking at the incoming request, and trying to fetch the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` - not there yet.

## EDIT 3

I ended up just using the Django session as is - once the user authenticates with AWS-Cognito once, it is safe to assume that it is a legitimate User.
Then I just dump the Cognito-JWT, and `login()` the User.

## Note: I am still interested in a solution that would drop the Django session for using the Cognito-JWT, and would love to hear suggestions.